# how to save bool value in KeychainItemWrapper

Tags: ios, boolean, keychainitemwrapper

I want to store bool value in KeychainItemWrapper, how to store ?

I have tried this code, but it gives me error.

```
 [keychain setObject:YES forKey:(__bridge BOOL)kSecAttrIsInvisible];
```

Comment: what's the error are you getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `BOOL` is a primitive type and the `setObject:forKey:` only excepts classes that derive from `NSObject`.

So use [`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/index.html) it has a special method for it [`+ numberWithBool:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNumber/numberWithBool:):

```
[keychain setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"someKey"];
```

And if you need to bool again:

```
 NSNumber *value = [keychain objectForKey:@"someKey"];
 BOOL boolValue = [value boolValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use Shorthand like

```
[keychain setObject:@(YES) forKey:(__bridge BOOL)kSecAttrIsInvisible];
```

Comment: Shorthand are called Literals and are not a feature of Objective-C 2.0 but [Clang 3.7](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) and used in LLVM 4.0